# Pandas: Reading CSV files with different delimiters - merge error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, delimiter

I have 4 separate CSV files that I wish to read into Pandas. I want to merge these CSV files into one dataframe.

The problem is that the columns within the CSV files contain the following: , ; | and spaces. Therefore I have to use different delimiters when reading the different CSV files and do some transformations to get them in the correct format.

Each CSV file contains an 'ID' column. When I merge my dataframes, it is not done correctly and I get 'NaN' in the column which has been merged.

Do you have to use the same delimiter in order for the dataframes to merge properly?

Comment: please give more information, like examples rows of the different csv's, the resulting DataFrames, what method you use to merge, what is the result and the expected result

Comment: check that the merge columns came out as the same type in both dataframes - if it is a string or object in one and a integer in the other it will not merge.

Comment: @Stael this worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @user7689492 lol, I've done it plenty of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short : no, you do not need similar delimiters within your files to merge pandas Dataframes - in fact, once data has been imported (which requires setting the right delimiter for each of your files), the data is placed in memory and does not keep track of the initial delimiter (you can see this by writing down your imported dataframes to csv using the `.to_csv` method : the delimiter will always be `,` by default).

Now, in order to understand what is going wrong with your merge, please post more details about your data and the code your are using to perform the operation.